# How to use searchBar in tableView to search cells with data and filter

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a table view with cells. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

The main question is how it possible to make, that when user write "Test", so it should show all what match for this word. Here is some method, which I've tried to use, but it's not working:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchedArray = activeStates.filter({ titleClass -> Bool in
            titleClass.title!.contains(searchText)
        })
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Now, I will show all data which I have. `var activeStates: [ActiveState] = [].` Here is my tableView methods:

```
    extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 118
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let classCell = cell as! ClassTableViewCell
            classCell.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
            classCell.imgClass.image = nil
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let classCell = cell as! ClassTableViewCell
            let asCell = self.activeStates[indexPath.row]
            classCell.lblTitle.text = asCell.title
            if let imageUrl: String = asCell.thumbnailUrl {
                if imageUrl != "" {
                    classCell.imgClass.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
                }
            } else {
                classCell.imgClass.image = UIImage(named: "classImagePlaceholder")
            }
            classCell.unreadClassImage.isHidden = unreadManager.unreadTable[asCell.idKey] == nil
            classCell.lblTitle.font = unreadManager.unreadTable[asCell.idKey] == nil ? Constants.CustomFont.customFontSemiBold : Constants.CustomFont.customFontBold
            classCell.classId = asCell.idKey
            classCell.selectionStyle = .none
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            store.dispatch(NavigationAction(destination: .paymentScreen, direction: .forward))
            print("SelecterRow")
        }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return activeStates.count
    }
    //swiftlint:disable force_cast
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        switch tableView {
        case tableView:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "classCell", for: indexPath)
        case secondTableView:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "classCell", for: indexPath) 
        default:
            print("Something goes wrong")
        }
//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "classCell", for: indexPath) as! ClassTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
```

I think, maybe need to filter titleName of the cell or something else.

Answer (score 0):

when you are in "searching state" you should get your data from the filtered array (searchedArray) and not from the original activeState array, in your case try something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let classCell = cell as! ClassTableViewCell
            let asCell = searching ? self.searchedArray[indexPath.row] :self.activeStates[indexPath.row]
            classCell.lblTitle.text = asCell.title
            if let imageUrl: String = asCell.thumbnailUrl {
                if imageUrl != "" {
                    classCell.imgClass.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
                }
            } else {
                classCell.imgClass.image = UIImage(named: "classImagePlaceholder")
            }
            classCell.unreadClassImage.isHidden = unreadManager.unreadTable[asCell.idKey] == nil
            classCell.lblTitle.font = unreadManager.unreadTable[asCell.idKey] == nil ? Constants.CustomFont.customFontSemiBold : Constants.CustomFont.customFontBold
            classCell.classId = asCell.idKey
            classCell.selectionStyle = .none
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            store.dispatch(NavigationAction(destination: .paymentScreen, direction: .forward))
            print("SelecterRow")
        }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
           return searchedArray.count
        }
        return activeStates.count
    }
```

EDIT:
set the searching variable using the UISearchBarDelegate:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searching = true
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searching = false
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchedArray = activeStates.filter({ titleClass -> Bool in
            titleClass.title!.contains(searchText)
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Getting error "Index out of range" here: let asCell = searching ? self.searchedArray[indexPath.row] :self.activeStates[indexPath.row]